# Ubuntu Studio Package Manager places app in menu category Other which is not visible

Tags: ubuntu-studio, appmenu, system-monitor

After installing MATE system monitor on Ubuntu Studio I discover that the application is put in menu category Other. The category is not visible though and I cant find how to make it so.
Also tried to use the Ubuntu Studio menu item editor and change the menu folder but regardless how I try my choice is ignored.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu Studio? How do you know it is in that category? In my 18.04 I can see the Other category just fine.

Comment: Its Ubuntu Studio 20.04 with Xfce. I "know" its in Other because it looks like that in Ubuntu Studio menu item editor (but it seems, to me, impossible to change)

Comment: Okay...when I check out some applications in UbuntuStudio Menu Item Editor that claim they are in category "Other", they actually seem to be in "Accessories". Have you checked there? Also, you may not be able to change the category without sudo rights - try starting the editor with `sudo ubuntustudio-menu-add`.

Comment: Its not in Accessories. Trying the

Comment: sudo ubuntustudio-menu-add gives 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntustudio-menu-add", line 369, in submenu_cb
    self.save()
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntustudio-menu-add", line 279, in save
    outf = open (outfile, 'w')

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.local/share/applications/mate-system-monitor.desktop'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntustudio-menu-add", line 369, in submenu_cb
    self.save()
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntustudio-menu-add", line 279, in save
    outf = open (outfile, 'w')

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.local/share/applications/mate-system-monitor.desktop'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntustudio-menu-add", line 358, in menu_cb
    self.save()
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntustudio-menu-add", line 279, in save
    outf = open (outfile, 'w')

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.local/share/applications/mate-system-monitor.desktop'
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntustudio-menu-add", line 440, in <module>
    Gtk.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 1632, in main
    return _Gtk_main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 120, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_ossighelper.py", line 251, in register_sigint_fallback
    signal.default_int_handler(signal.SIGINT, None)

Comment: Please try to put that output into your additional post, otherwise it's hard to read. But it seems you have some problem there.